# podman: How to know the process is running inside the podman

Tags: podman

I am running some applications where application must know that it is running inside the PODMAN without any extra env variable but podman configuration inside the container must provide the detail without any user interactions.

As of now, I am using cat `/proc/self/cgroup| grep -i 'machine.slice/libpod-*'` inside the container started using podman to check if the process is inside the pod or not.

Is there a better way to handle the same?

Answer (score 4):

From purely theoretical standpoint, using the approach with `/proc/self/cgroup` is a bad idea, as it is not guaranteed that the container engine would not spawn a container in a new cgroup namespace so that the containerized process would see its current cgroups simply as `/` like in the following example (`unshare -C` here emulates the container engine unsharing the cgroup namespace when starting the container):

```
$ podman run -it --privileged archlinux/base
[root@da0277b524db /]# unshare -C
-sh-5.0# cat /proc/self/cgroup
12:freezer:/
11:perf_event:/
10:pids:/
9:blkio:/
8:hugetlb:/
7:rdma:/
6:cpu,cpuacct:/
5:cpuset:/
4:net_cls,net_prio:/
3:memory:/
2:devices:/
1:name=systemd:/
0::/
```

From practical standpoint, container engines seem to care about compatibility with this trick, e.g. [Moby uses the host cgroup namespace by default](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/072400fc4b8d6a38a2007d41072b765666a4c288), and Podman seems to use the host cgroup namespace too, so this popular dirty check *should* succeed, but it is still an exploitation of an *unintentional isolation breach*, which exists since the times when the cgroup namespaces just did not exist.

What are alternatives?

When speaking about Podman specifically, it seems that the container engine inserts a special environment variable during the [container spec creation](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/81c543bbe3cd5130b5a2f163011d59d8b09f6877/pkg/specgen/generate/oci.go#L275) to indicate that the containerized process is started using a specific container engine. So, even when you start your container without any additional variables, you may find the `container` variable in its place:

```
$ podman run -it alpine
/ # env | grep container
container=podman
```

While this approach is not bulletproof too (as nothing stops the container creator from overriding this variable), I feel that it is *much* better than the trick with `/proc/self/cgroup`, as this stuff is provided by the container engine *intentionally*, and it is unlikely to be overridden *inadvertently*, as this variable does not follow the general naming convention and does not use the `ALL_CAPS` style.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up for anyone that might be looking for a similar solution I found that with Podman version 4.4.1 running on RHEL8.8, containers created by Podman do in fact have a `container` environment variable but the value is `oci` not `podman` as documented in the previous comment.

```
# env | grep container
container=oci
```

I also found that Docker containers created under RHEL7 with Docker version 24.0.4 also have the same value (`oci`) for containers.

The only potential indicator I have found so far is in Control Groups; `/proc/self/cgroup`, which was declared above to be unreliable.  In my Podman containers the values are:

```
# cat /proc/self/cgroup
12:freezer:/
11:pids:/user.slice/user-1001.slice/session-50.scope
10:rdma:/
9:blkio:/system.slice/sshd.service
8:perf_event:/
7:net_cls,net_prio:/
6:cpuset:/
5:hugetlb:/
4:devices:/system.slice/sshd.service
3:memory:/user.slice/user-1001.slice/session-50.scope
2:cpu,cpuacct:/
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-1001.slice/user@1001.service/user.slice/podman-680338.scope/b55775c974c61b9edb95772ef5513cfcf341460f5613cc5d22bf97c0a81d6e04
```

Where in the Docker containers the values all start `/docker`.

```
# cat /proc/self/cgroup
11:devices:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
10:freezer:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
9:hugetlb:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
8:cpuset:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
7:blkio:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
6:pids:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
5:perf_event:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
4:net_prio,net_cls:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
3:memory:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
2:cpuacct,cpu:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d77
1:name=systemd:/docker/65d6fc6dd15cf0d221fd96b4d07438cf4357edc6f835e31e37aa35b3db0b7d7
```

So for my runtime environments, the `/proc/self/cgroups` solution is the only viable one.